# How to use Material-ui@next TextField error props

Tags: material-ui

I want to use Material-UI Next textfield `error` props [link](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/#textfield), the props type is `boolean`. The previous version of Material-UI props name is `errorText` and the props type is `node` [link](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field).

Textfield Material-UI previous version using `errorText` props :

```
<TextField
  name='name'
  floatingLabelText='Name'
  hintText='Type your name'
  value={this.state.fields.name}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  errorText={this.state.error}
/>
```

With `errorText` in Material-UI previous version, the code works good for displaying an error state.

Textfield Material-UI Next using `error` props:

```
<TextField
  name='name'
  label='Name'
  placeholder='Type your name'
  value={this.state.fields.name}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  error={true} //only accept true or false value
/>
```

On Material-UI Next `errorText` props changed to `error` with boolean type and only accept true or false value. If i set the `error` props to true, the textfield displaying error state at any time. I just want to displaying error state under certain conditions.

How can i use error state `this.state.error` on Material-UI Next textfield?

Comment: Why don't you keep the error condition in the component state?

Comment: @galah92 do you mean `error={this.state.error}`?

Comment: Exactly. I'm using a variant of `value={this.state.value}` and `error={this.state.value === ""}`.

Comment: @galah92 with `value={this.state.value}` and `error={this.state.value === ""}` it not shown an error message, i tried to use `error={this.state.error}` but nothing happens. I want to show an error message with red text color if error happens. As use `errorText` property at the previous version of material-ui.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Using a react component state, one can store the `TextField` value and use that as an indicator for an error. Material-UI exposes the `error` and `helperText` props to display an error interactively.

Take a look at the following example:

```
<TextField
  value={this.state.text}
  onChange={event => this.setState({ text: event.target.value })}
  error={text === ""}
  helperText={text === "" ? 'Empty field!' : ' '}
/>
```

Comment: With MUI 3, helperText requires a React Node

Answer (score 6):

I add an example that does not shows an error when the value is empty and validates a regular expression (MAC Address).

```
<TextField id="macAddress" label="MAC Address" name="macAddress"
  value={this.state.macAddress}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  error={this.state.macAddress !== "" && !this.state.macAddress.match("^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$")}
  helperText={this.state.macAddress !== "" && !this.state.macAddress.match("^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$") ? 'MAC Address must be a 6-bytes string.' : ' '}
/>
```